# Are NSGarbageCollector's disableCollectorForPointer: calls balanced by enableCollectorForPointer: calls?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, garbage-collection

**Situation:**

I need to pass an Objective-C object to an asynchronous C API as an opaque reference (`void*`) which will later be passed to the callback function I provide. The callback then calls a method on the object. The code needs to work in the presence of garbage collection, and the object must not be GC'd between my call to the C API and the time my callback is called by it.

The `NSGarbageCollector` class provides the [`disableCollectorForPointer:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSGarbageCollector_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSGarbageCollector/disableCollectorForPointer%3a) and `enableCollectorForPointer:` methods for marking and unmarking objects as uncollectable roots.

**Question:**

What I can't work out from the docs and searching the web is if the calls to `disableCollectorForPointer:` are counted and must be balanced by the same number of `enableCollectorForPointer:` calls. If this is *not* the case and each object is either flagged as root or not, calling `enableCollectorForPointer:` in my callback might clear an existing root flag set by some other code, causing the object to be collected even though it shouldn't!

The alternative I've seen is to use `CFRetain` and `CFRelease` - are these safe to use on my own `NSObject` subclasses? I've only used these functions on toll-free-bridged CF objects before.

Bonus points for answers which provide evidence. I see `disableCollectorForPointer:` recommended all over the place, with no mention of this safety aspect.

**Notes:**

- I have to support garbage collection as this code will be used by a PrefPane for System Preferences. The 64-bit version of a PrefPane *must* use garbage collection. So using ARC or manual refcounting is not an option.
- The C API is one of Apple's (IOKit) so I have no control over it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the answer. Source code for the garbage collector doesn't seem to be available, but the header file declaring the interface for `NSGarbageCollector`, `NSGarbageCollector.h` from the `Foundation.framework` contains the following:

```
// references outside the heap, globals, and the stack, e.g. unscanned memory, malloc memory, must be tracked by the collector
- (void)disableCollectorForPointer:(void *)ptr;     // this pointer will not be collected...
- (void)enableCollectorForPointer:(void *)ptr;      // ...until this (stacking) call is made
```

Note the **"stacking"** comment - I assume this means that calls are indeed counted? More evidence still welcome!

**Update:**

Just to be really sure, I decided to test my hypothesis using a little test program (**gcbridgetest.m**):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface PJGarbageCollectionTest : NSObject
@end

@implementation PJGarbageCollectionTest

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;
    NSLog(@"%@ -init", self);
    return self;
}

- (void)finalize
{
    NSLog(@"%@ -finalize", self);
    [super finalize];
}

@end

static void* ext_ptr1 = NULL;
static void* ext_ptr2 = NULL;

static void create()
{
    PJGarbageCollectionTest* test = [[PJGarbageCollectionTest alloc] init];
    [[NSGarbageCollector defaultCollector] disableCollectorForPointer:test];
    ext_ptr1 = test;
    [[NSGarbageCollector defaultCollector] disableCollectorForPointer:test];
    ext_ptr2 = test;
}

static void killref(void** ext_ptr)
{
    [[NSGarbageCollector defaultCollector] enableCollectorForPointer:*ext_ptr];
    *ext_ptr = NULL;
}


int main()
{
    NSLog(@"collector: %@", [NSGarbageCollector defaultCollector]);
    create();
    NSLog(@"Collecting with 2 external references");
    [[NSGarbageCollector defaultCollector] collectExhaustively];
    killref(&ext_ptr1);
    NSLog(@"Collecting with 1 external reference");
    [[NSGarbageCollector defaultCollector] collectExhaustively];
    killref(&ext_ptr2);
    NSLog(@"Collecting with 0 external references");
    [[NSGarbageCollector defaultCollector] collectExhaustively];
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `gcc -fobjc-gc-only -g -Wall -Wextra -ObjC gcbridgetest.m -framework Foundation -o gcbridgetest` and run as `./gcbridgetest`, it gives the following output, confirming that enable/disableCollectorForPointer: calls are indeed counted:

```
2012-06-12 16:08:08.278 gcbridgetest[29712:903] collector: <NSGarbageCollector: 0x20000f420>
2012-06-12 16:08:08.281 gcbridgetest[29712:903] <PJGarbageCollectionTest: 0x20000ee60> -init
2012-06-12 16:08:08.284 gcbridgetest[29712:903] Collecting with 2 external references
2012-06-12 16:08:08.285 gcbridgetest[29712:903] Collecting with 1 external reference
2012-06-12 16:08:08.286 gcbridgetest[29712:903] Collecting with 0 external references
2012-06-12 16:08:08.286 gcbridgetest[29712:903] <PJGarbageCollectionTest: 0x20000ee60> -finalize
```